# mapping the shift key in vim

Tags: coffeescript, vim

I'm having an issue when mapping the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key in VIM. I want <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to behave differently than <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>

so I have this

```
" for insert mode remap <c-l> to:
" Insert a hash rocket  for ruby
" Insert a -> for php
" for coffee the shift key decides

function! SmartHash(...)
  let shift = a:0 > 0
  let ruby = &ft == 'ruby'
  let php = &ft == 'php'
  let coffee = &ft == 'coffee'

  if php
    return "\->"
  end

  if coffee
    return shift ? "\ =>\n" : "\ ->\n"
  end

  if ruby
    return "\ => "
  end

  return ""

endfunction

imap <c-l> <c-r>=SmartHash()<cr>
imap <C-S-L> <c-r>=SmartHash(1)<cr>
```

...but it's just triggering the second mapping whether I have the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key pressed or not.

#### Updated based on [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10345866/80559)

```
" for insert mode remap <c-l> to:
" Insert a hash rocket  for ruby
" Insert a -> for php and coffeescript
" double tapping does alternate symbol for php and coffescript
function! SmartHash(...)
  let alt = a:0 > 0
  let ruby = &ft == 'ruby'
  let php = &ft == 'php'
  let coffee = &ft == 'coffee'

  if php || coffee
    return alt ? "\ =>\n" : "\ ->\n"
  end

  if ruby
    return "\ => "
  end

  return ""

endfunction

imap <c-l> <c-r>=SmartHash()<cr>
imap <c-l><c-l> <c-r>=SmartHash(1)<cr>
```

Comment: If you're using terminal-based `vim`, there's no difference between `c-l` and `c-s-l`.  The GUI (`gvim`) may be able to map these keys.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Due to the way that the keyboard input is handled internally, this unfortunately isn't possible today, even in GVIM. This is a known pain point, and the subject of various discussions on vim_dev and the #vim IRC channel.

Some people (foremost Paul LeoNerd Evans) want to fix that (even for console Vim in terminals that support this), and have floated various proposals, cp. http://groups.google.com/group/vim_dev/browse_thread/thread/626e83fa4588b32a/bfbcb22f37a8a1f8

But as of today, no patches or volunteers have yet come forward, though many have expressed a desire to have this in a future Vim 8 major release.

I usually work around this by starting my alternate mapping with `g`, e.g. `<C-l>` and `g<C-l>`, but that won't work in insert mode. In your case, with a little bit of additional logic, you could make a second `<C-l>` at the same position change the previously inserted `->` to `=>`, so that you get the first alternative via `<C-l>`, and the second via `<C-l><C-l>`.

Comment: that's pretty great. It's more versatile that what I originally had.