# VIM how to map the combine key: ctrl+shift+w+,

Tags: vim

As we know, the combine key:`ctrl+shift+w+,`
can help us resize the window, but i think it is complex, so i want to map it with `ctrl + ,`. But all my way is not work. anyone who can give me some advice?

Comment: Explain with more words. What you wanted to do exactly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mapping the shift key in vim](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10340470/mapping-the-shift-key-in-vim)

Answer (score 5):

Vim and gVim don't detect the <kbd>shift</kbd> in such a combination, i.e., <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> is exactly the same as <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>.

> As we know, the combine key:ctrl+shift+w+, can help us resize the
>   window, (...)

There is no such built-in command -- you can check all the available window related commands in [`:help ctrl-w`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/index.txt.html#CTRL-W).

You are probably using some custom mapping; you could check this by using `:map` or `:map <c-w>`. Once you find the command triggered by that mapping you can create your simpler mapping.

But note that note all key combinations are available. In special, the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> combination isn't detected by Vim, as noted at [Vim FAQ 20.5](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-20.5):

```
20.5. Why does mapping the <C-...> key not work?

The only Ctrl-printable-key chords which Vim can reliably detect (because they
are defined in the ASCII standard) are the following: >

        Ctrl-@                 0x00            NUL
        Ctrl-A to Ctrl-Z       0x01 to 0x1A
        Ctrl-a to Ctrl-z       0x01 to 0x1A
        Ctrl-[                 0x1B            ESC
        Ctrl-\                 0x1C
        Ctrl-]                 0x1D
        Ctrl-^                 0x1E
        Ctrl-_                 0x1F
        Ctrl-?                 0x7F            DEL

        (...)

You can try other combinations of Ctrl + any key, but they may either
not work everywhere (e.g. the terminal might not pass that key to Vim,
or they might have unintended side effects (e.g. mapping <C-I> means
also to map <Tab>).
```

You can find more information at [20.4. I am not able to create a mapping for the  key. What is wrong?](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-20.4)